# Slurm setup: Error connecting slurm stream socket

Tags: slurm

I am trying to setup a new cluster with slurm. I have setup a client and a control machine.  (I am new to this .....)

1. When I type **sinfo -vvv** from control machine it is telling

" sinfo: debug2: slurm_connect failed: Connection refused
  sinfo: debug2: Error connecting slurm stream socket at 192.168.155.142:6817: Connection refused "

My slurm is configured to use 6817 port (full config is available here https://pastebin.com/X4yDe99z

`SlurmctldPort=6817`

The port is open ( I tried with ufw disabled also)

`6817 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`

2. When I try **slurmctld -Dvvv** it is showing this error

`slurmctld: error: this host (xxxx/xxx) not a valid controller (gaia or (null))`

My /etc/hosts file is

`127.0.0.1    localhost
192.168.155.142 gaia`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the parameter `ControlMachine` in `slurm.conf`, the machine on which you start `slurmctld`, must be the exact output of `hostname -s` on that machine for the daemon to start.

It seems `hostname -s` on your machine does not output `gaia`. Replace `gaia` with what is hidden behind `xxxx/xxx`.